# shell operators confusion

Tags: shell-script, shell

I don't know how to title this question but anyway

```
a="$(file . * | grep -i pgp)" || echo "no such files found! " && exit \
        && b=$(echo "$a" | fzf --cycle --height=15) && [ -n "$b" ] \
        && gpg --import "$b"
```

I'm confused about this. When variable `a` does not exist prints `echo "no such files found! "` and exits but when does exist doesn't print the message and exits as well. How can I do to exit only when no value is passed to variable `a`, in other words, when variable `a` does not exist.

Comment: `||` and `&&` look at the exit status of the latest executed command. If the `grep` in the assignment to `a` returns a falsy status, the `||` is fulfilled and the `echo` runs. It in turn almost certainly returns a truthy status, which `&&` looks for, so the `exit` runs. On the other hand, if the `grep` returns a truthy status, the `echo` is skipped, but the `exit` runs. The combination of `&&` and `||` isn't the same as `if-else`, which I think you probably should use here.

Comment: yeah, normally I use operators but I ended up with the `if` statement, I was just curious about this behaviour @ilkkachu

Comment: I guess you could do something like `a=$(whatever) || { echo "error"; exit; } && echo success && some commands`. The braces would group the `echo` and `exit`, and in the failing case, the shell would exit before the `&&` is checked. But just `if a=$(whatever); then echo success; ...; else echo error; exit; fi` would still be clearer